# Disconnect PostgreSQL when client goes to new page

Tags: node.js, postgresql, real-time

I'm trying to build a real time web page and use postgreSQL as my database. I use node.js and express to build backend stuff. Since this is a real time webpage and needs to update information very frequently, I keep a long connection with postgreSQL, which looks like:

```
app.get('/:A/:B', function(req,res){

  var A = req.params.A;
  var B = req.params.B;
  var client = new pg.Client(config[A][B]);

  client.connect(function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error occurred when try to connect the database",err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Connected to the database");
    }
  });
  Do some queries with current database connection...
}
```

The problem is, when I change the value of A and B in browser and try to connect to a new database, I didn't disconnect with the old one so the info on my page are still from the old database. I'm new to node and web development. Can anyone let me know how to disconnect with the old database when client try to go to a new url?

Answer (score 0):

I think is not good way to create connection for each request. If size of A-B variants is limited then create of connection pool on start is better.

```
app.get('/:A/:B', function(req, res, next){ // next to forwarding error
     var A = req.params.A;
     var B = req.params.B;
     var client = new pg.Client(config[A][B]);

      client.connect(function(err){
          if (err) 
              return next(err); // go to error-middleware

          console.log("Connected to the database");

          // Do some queries with current database connection...
          // Keep it mind that they're also asynchronous, so better way is use promises or async (https://github.com/caolan/async)

          client.end(function (err) {
              if (err) 
                 next(err);
          });
      });
}

// Error middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url, err.message);
})
```